# Substitute for Association inside Compile?

Tags: compile, associations, data-structures

`Association`s are not compilable, so I’m looking for a workaround to this. That is, I need a mutable hashtable-like data structure with  fast key value lookups within `Compile`?

**Basic non-working example:**

```
cf = FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[arg, "Integer64"]},
    Module[{Typed[ds, 
        TypeSpecifier["HashTable"]["Integer64", "Integer64"]] = 
       CreateDataStructure["HashTable"]},
     ds["Insert", 1 -> 2];
     ds[arg]]]
   ];
```

[image]

Comment: The basic data types are scalars and arrays of them.  You'd have to implement something in terms of those, I think.

Comment: What type of keys do you intend on having?

Comment: The keys are Integers

Comment: How large is the spread of keys? Maybe a simple array (possibly with shifted indexing) suffices?

Comment: Unknown - spreads are arbitrary

Comment: If you're willing to use `FunctionCompile` you can use `CreateDataStructure["HashTable"]`

Answer (score 16):

For what it's worth, you *can* work with a `HashTable` as long as you're willing to put in a bit of effort

```
fc =
  FunctionCompile[
   Function[{
     Typed[keys, "PackedArray"["MachineInteger", 1]], 
     Typed[values, "FixedArray"["Expression"]]
     },
    Block[{ds = CreateDataStructure["HashTable"]},
     Do[ds["Insert", keys[[i]], values[[i]]], {i, Length[keys]}];
     ds["Lookup", 7]
     ]
    ]
   ];

words = RandomWord[10000];
keys = RandomInteger[1000, 10000];
fa = CreateDataStructure["FixedArray", Length@words];
Do[fa["SetPart", i, words[[i]]], {i, Length@words}];

fc[keys, fa]

"imperceptible"
```

Here's a potentially more useful example where we first create our `HashTable` as a proper compiled data structure and then work with it

```
words = RandomWord[10000];
keys = RandomInteger[100000, 10000];
fa = CreateDataStructure["FixedArray", Length@words];
Do[fa["SetPart", i, words[[i]]], {i, Length@words}];

initTable =
  FunctionCompile[
   Function[{
     Typed[keys, "PackedArray"["MachineInteger", 1]], 
     Typed[values, "FixedArray"["Expression"]]
     },
    Block[{ds = CreateDataStructure["HashTable"]},
     Do[ds["Insert", keys[[i]], values[[i]]], {i, Length[keys]}];
     ds
     ]
    ]
   ];

lookupKeys = FunctionCompile[
   Function[{
     Typed[ds, TypeSpecifier["HashTable"]["Integer64", "Expression"]],
     Typed[keys, "PackedArray"["MachineInteger", 1]],
     Typed[default, "Expression"]
     },
    Block[{res = CreateDataStructure["FixedArray", Length@keys], val},
     Do[
      val = If[ds["KeyExistsQ", keys[[i]]], ds["Lookup", keys[[i]]], default];
      res["SetPart", i, val], 
      {i, Length[keys]}
      ];
     res
     ]
    ]
   ];

table = initTable[keys, fa];
Normal@lookupKeys[table, RandomInteger[1000, 5], None]

{None, None, "condescending", None, "canon"}
```

and obviously you can do much more with this than what is here

Comment: @user5601 there isn't a limit on the `HashTable` (I think). I just needed a fixed number for initialization but you can update that at any time

Comment: Ok, but how to use your `initTable` and `lookupKeys` from inside a `FunctionCompile`? Is there someway to add them like `CompilerEnvironmentAppendTo[..., {initTable, lookupKeys}]` without having to figure out types again and put them in `DeclareFunction`s?